# AngularJS ngSubmit only dirty fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was wondering if there is a way to submit the form with only `$dirty` fields, currently I am using `ng-change` to manually add every field to the request on change. But the problem with that is, its not very reusable.

in form.html

```
<input name="status" id="status" ng-model="campaign.status" ng-change="change('status')">
```

in controller.js

```
$scope.updates = {};
$scope.change = function (field) {
    $scope.updates[field] = $scope.campaign[field];
};
Campaign.update({id: $scope.campaign.id}, $scope.updates).$promise.then(function () {
    // success
}, function () {
    //error
});
```

I am looking for a better way to do this, maybe for example without the `updates` variable.

Comment: Could the input be empty or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me that you only want to send fields that have been updated.  I'm not quite sure what the reasoning is for this, but if the problem you want to solve is only submitting changed values, I would like to suggest an alternate approach.

If you can use a library like lodash or underscore, my suggestion would be to do a diff of an original copy and the current instance of `$scope.campaigns` before submitting.

The reasons are as follows:

- The listener function of `$scope.$watch` is not flexible enough to easily use to create your `$scope.updates` object object.
- The `$dirty` state of your form will be a bit fragile because the `$dirty` property requires that you use the name property of the form field, not the name of the `ng-model` attribute. This can cause naming conflicts and tends to not be very portable or update friendly.

If you were using lodash you might do something like:

```
//as soon as you create $scope.campaign, copy it to $scope.original
$scope.original = angular.copy($scope.campaign);

//in your update function
$scope.updates = _.pick($scope.campaign, function(value, key, object){ return $scope.campaign[key] != $scope.original[key] });

Campaign.update({id: $scope.campaign.id}, $scope.updates).$promise.then(function () {
        // success
    }, function () {
        //error
    });
```

---

Comment: In the case of using _.difference() be aware that when using it with a list that contains objects that have the same value multiple times and you change the value to match a different value share between object, it will NOT return that result. Ex: _difference([{a:1},{a:1},{a:2}], [{a:2},{a:1},{a:2}]) returns an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

For each field in the form, there is a property `$dirty` on it. When submitting the form, you can iterate through the fields and pick those `$dirty`.

Try `console.log($scope.formName.status)` to check those properties.

Comment: I'm getting `undefined` for `scope.formName.status`, but the form is marked as dirty.

Answer (score 0):

You can also invalid it until every fields are dirty:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/grzww09w/)

```
<form name="test">
    <input name="status" id="status" ng-model="campaign.status" ng-change="change('status')">
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="!test.status.$dirty">Send</button>
</form>
```